# Find a function with certain properties

Tags: functions

For some reason I'm interested in the following problem. Find a function of two variables $f(a,b)$ such that
$$
1) f(a+b,b)=f(a,b),\quad \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}\\
2) f(a,b)=\sin 2\pi ab,\quad
 \text{if} \quad \forall a\in \mathbb{R},\forall b\in \mathbb{Z}$$
This is not a textbook problem. Maybe the solution is simple but I just can't see it, maybe there is no solution but I'm not able to show it.

Any tips are welcome.

Sorry for being unclear.

Addition:
I would like the function to be "nice" in both of its arguments. Probably analytic but that is debatable. In a sense I'm looking for analytic continuation of the $\sin2\pi ab$ preserving the periodicity property (1).

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense as written.  Maybe someone misunderstood the source?

Comment: I am the source in this case :) What is wrong with the problem posing?

Comment: Is line 1 supposed to be true for all real $a$ and $b$?  Is line 2 supposed to be true for all real $a$ and all integer $b$?  $f(a,b) = \sin 2\pi a b$ pretty much defines a function on the $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ domain, and you don't seem to have many restrictions at all on the $b \notin \mathbb{Z}$ domain.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. The main restriction (still  sloppy posed though) is that the function is "nice", probably analytic in both arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you define $f(a,b)=0$ when $b\not\in{\Bbb Z}$, then:

If $b\not\in{\Bbb Z}:\ f(a+b,b)=0=f(a,b)$.

If $b\in{\Bbb Z}:\ f(a+b,b)=\sin2\pi(a+b)b=\sin(2\pi ab+2\pi b^2)=\sin(2\pi ab)
=f(a,b).$

The zero in the first case is irrelevant. Any $g(b)$ is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Unfortunately, such discontinuous function is not what I am looking for, see addition to the question.